# Is it possible to detect TileWMS layer by click on map?

Tags: openlayers

[image: http://screen.kroxus.net/umid/20150726-989-8kb.jpg]

Here is a map with TileWMS.

Is it possible to detect if a user clicked on a red square?

How can I detect by mouse clicking on the map to get the TileWMS layer?

Comment: Did you see [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html)?

Comment: If you need the click event, you should use WFS and not WMS.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the documentation as well, but finally I came up with this code that worked for me:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
    map.forEachLayerAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(layer){ 
        if(layer===layerName) {
            console.log('layer clicked');
        } 
    });
});
```

You just have to replace "layerName" with the name of your layer.

Comment: i tried to use your answer since it is perfect for what I was looking for but it crashed and showed this message in the firebug console `Security Error: The operation is insecure` and it happens **only** when I use `forEachLayerAtPixel` (for instance, I tried to use `forEachFeatureAtPixel` just to see what happened and nothing happened nor an error was thrown), please if you have encountered this error before, could you give any useful pointers as how to resolve it, thanx

Comment: @Umid Abulkasimov; this is for the asker to b notified as well, please Umid, take a look at my previous comment and see if u can help, tell if I should post a question for this, thanx

Answer (score 0):

If your TileWMS has only red dot you can use the  [map.forEachLayerAtPixel](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachLayerAtPixel)  function to detect if you layer display something on a specific pixel. Here is [a official working example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html?q=forEachLayerAtPixel)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @oterral worked for me. ImageWMS was not being detected with `forEachFeatureAtPixel` and it was returning only vector layers. If you wish to detect your ImageWMS layer at pixel you have to use `map.forEachLayerAtPixel`. This is for those who are wondering why my layer is not shown while running `forEachFeatureAtPixel`.